# Push Notification from cloud code returning JSON error

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform, push-notification, parse-server

I am trying to initiate a push notification from cloud code, but I always receive this error

```
{
  "code":107,
  "message":"Received an error with invalid JSON from Parse: Cannot POST /push\n"
}
```

I am running `parse-server@2.2.21`

```
Parse.Cloud.define("SendPushNotif", function(request, response){

  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
  query.equalTo('channels', ["Giants"]);

  Parse.Push.send({
    where: query,
    data: {
      "title": "Test",
      "alert": "This is a test push notification"
    }
  }, { useMasterKey: true })
  .then(function() {
      response.success(response);
    }, function(error) {
      response.success(error);
  });
});
```

Comment: looks like there is a comma missing after "Test"

Comment: oh that's my fault in the copy and paste, but my code has the comma

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? @joethemow